# BCRYPT issue pulling from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Novice in my programming endeavors, but I am stuck and cannot find any help. I am able to register users into my db and hash the password. I am trying to be able to login with that user. I am able to check for required field in email and password, but when I enter a user in the db with the correct password the page hangs.

```
'''
exports.login = (req,res) =>{
        try {
            const {email, password} = req.body;
            if (!email || !password){
                return res.status(400).render('login', {
                    message: 'Email and password required.'
                })
            }

            db.query ('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results)=> {
               if(error)
               console.log(error)

               if(!results){
                res.status(401).render('login', {
                    message: 'Invalid email or password.'
                })
                }else{
                   await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, results.password)
                        if(bool == false){
                            res.status(401).render('login', {
                                message: 'Invalid password.'
                        })
                    }else{
                        res.status(401).render('index', {
                            message: 'User Logged in'
                         });    
                }

            }
        })

        } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
    }
}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function : (bcryptCompare.js)

```
const checkBcrypt = async function(pass, hash) {
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    bcrypt.compare(pass, hash, function(bcryptErr, bcryptRes) {
      if (bcryptErr) {
        console.log('ERROR -> BCRYPT');
        return resolve(false);
      } else {
        if (!bcryptRes) {
          return resolve(false);
        } else {
          return resolve(true);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = checkBcrypt;
```

You can use it like this:

```
const checkBcrypt = require('./bcryptCompare');

const checkPass = await checkBcrypt(req.body.password, results.password);
if(checkPass){
   //
} else {
   //invalid password
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me with this issue. I am fooling around with what you have provided me and trying to get it running in my application. Thank you, will report back soon!